# fill missing values in python array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Using: Python 2.7.1 on Windows

Hello, I fear this question has a very simple answer, but I just can't seem to find an appropriate and efficient solution (I have limited python experience). I am writing an application that just downloads historic weather data from a third party API (wundergorund). The thing is, sometimes there's no value for a given hour (eg, we have 20 degrees at 5 AM, no value for 6 AM, and 21 degrees at 7 AM). I need to have exactly one temperature value in any given hour, so I figured I could just fit the data I do have and evaluate the points I'm missing (using SciPy's polyfit). That's all cool, however, I am having problems handling my program to detect if the list has missing hours, and if so, insert the missing hour and calculate a temperature value. I hope that makes sense..

My attempt at handling the hours and temperatures list is the following:

```
from scipy import polyfit

# Evaluate simple cuadratic function
def tempcal (array,x):

    return array[0]*x**2 + array[1]*x + array[2]


# Sample data, note it has missing hours.
# My final hrs list should look like range(25), with matching temperatures at every   point
hrs = [1,2,3,6,9,11,13,14,15,18,19,20]
temps = [14.0,14.5,14.5,15.4,17.8,21.3,23.5,24.5,25.5,23.4,21.3,19.8]

# Fit coefficients
coefs = polyfit(hrs,temps,2)

# Cycle control
i = 0
done = False

while not done:

    # It has missing hour, insert it and calculate a temperature
    if hrs[i] != i:

        hrs.insert(i,i)
        temps.insert(i,tempcal(coefs,i))

    # We are done, leave now
    if i == 24:

        done = True

    i += 1
```

I can see why this isn't working, the program will eventually try to access indexes out of range for the hrs list. I am also aware that modifying list's length inside a loop has to be done carefully. Surely enough I am either not being careful enough or just overlooking a simpler solution altogether.

In my googling attempts to help myself I came across pandas (the library) but I feel like I can solve this problem without it, (and I would rather do so).

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should use a `dictionary` instead of 2 lists: `weather_dict = {1:14.0,2:14.5,3:14.5,4: None, etc}`. You can initialize the `dict` with all arbitrary values and then fill in the data you do have.

Answer (score 0):

When I is equal 21. It means twenty second value in list. But there is only 21 values.

In future I recommend you to use [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) with breakpoints for debug. Or [try-except](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) construction.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i would recommend this way of interpolating values. I would have used the closest points surrounding the missing values instead of the whole dataset. But using numpy your proposed way is fairly straight forward.

```
hrs = np.array(hrs)
temps = np.array(temps)

newTemps = np.empty((25))
newTemps.fill(-300) #just fill it with some invalid data, temperatures don't go this low so it should be safe. 

#fill in original values
newTemps[hrs - 1] = temps 
#Get indicies of missing values
missing = np.nonzero(newTemps == -300)[0]

#Calculate and insert missing values. 
newTemps[missing] = tempcal(coefs, missing + 1)
```

Comment: I didn't know indexing like that was possible, but sure is helpful. Also I don't use numpy much, but I sure will try this out. Thanks a lot ! (Dont have enough rep to upvote your answer lol)